# Sharepoint 2013 reports being blocked until complete page load

Tags: sharepoint, reporting-services

On my site we have a dashboard with several report-viewers in a web part page. The reports load sequentially rather than synchronously. This is annoying but the worst part is that the reports that load first are blocked (whited-out) until all reports on the page have loaded. Is there any way to either:

```
 1. Allow all report-viewer web parts to load synchronously
```

OR

```
 2. Allow access to the first-to-finish reports while other reports load?
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, this is not possible. We have had these issues before and the out-of-the-box web parts are ridiculously slow. It took about 10 minutes (!!) to load all ~12 web parts. As soon as you add more than 2 it already becomes a pain.

We ended up creating custom web parts that are in fact iframes to the report. This way it all loads asynchronously in parallel. Page load decreased to ~20-30 seconds...